# Remote debugging in Visual Studio .NET 2003

Tags: .net, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

I have an old Windows application in C# and .NET Framework 1.1 in Visual Studio .NET 2003. I have built it in debug mode and then place it in a remote machine. Now what I am trying to do is to debug the application placed and running in the remote machine from my host/local machine where Visual Studio .NET 2003 IDE is installed.

I have seen some articles like [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318041/how-to-set-up-and-use-remote-debugging-in-visual-studio-.net-or-in-visual-studio-2005) . Also it seems like running the remote debugger from a file share in the remote machine is enough ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) it explains) but Does it matter where application is placed in the remote machine? Can be placed anywhere or in a specific path in order I can debug it from local machine where Visual Studio .NET 2003 is installed?

What are exactly the steps to be follow to debug a remote winform application?

I have followed what is said [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x6by8d2(v=vs.71).aspx) in case of C# project, that is:

- prepare the remote machine, copy .exe file and pdbs to a location in remote machine, i.e. c:\temp
- prepare the local machine (I have followed the steps commented in the above link to configure the project for remote debugging)
- In local machine where Visual Studio is installed, I have shared the folder where msvcmon.exe (remote debugger) is.
- Then I access from the remote machine to the shared folder in local machine, and launch msvcmon.exe in remote machine. It keeps waiting for connections.
- Finally, from Visual Studio .NET 2003 I start debugging the application. But below error appears:

> Access is denied. Verify that you are an Administrator or a member of
>   the 'Debugger Users' group on the machine you are trying to debug.
>   After being added to the 'Debugger Users' group, you must log off and
>   log back on for the setting to apply.

I am a little confused, Which user do I have to add to 'Debugger Users' group? my local user on local machine where vs .net 2003 is running? If so, my local user in local machine is already a member of 'Debugger Users' group in local machine, but it is not working.

Comment: You have to say goodbye to end-of-life stuffs.

Comment: @LexLi Yes, but depending on the case, there are situations where it comes imposed  and company for some reason don't want to migrate that application at least for now and needs quickly implement a modification and there is no time now for migrate (maybe in future).

Comment: @user1624552，Could you get useful information from my suggestion? If you get any latest information, please feel free to let me know. Of course, if possible, I suggest you higher VS version for remote debugging:)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could get useful information here:

> When you try to debug on a remote machine, the debugger does two things :
>
> > •First, the debugger attempts to connect to the remote
> >     debugging components. To connect to these components, you must be a
> >     member of the Debugger Users group on the remote machine or an
> >     Administrator on the remote machine.
> >
> > •Then, the debugger attempts to
> >     attach to the process. You must have the correct permissions to debug
> >     that process.**

For more detailed information, see:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291232(v=vs.71).aspx

In addition, VS.net 2003 was really old version, we didn't really use or support it, if possible, I suggest you use the latest VS version like VS2013, VS2015 or VS2017.

For the detailed permission requirements, see:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y5b4b4f(v=vs.120).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Start msvcmon.exe from the command line with the `-anyuser` option.